# Downsampling an image using sinc interpolation?

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, interpolation, downsampling, sinc

I have a discrete image of size $2^N \times 2^N$ which I would like to iteratively downsample to produce a pyramid with image sizes $2^k\times 2^k, \, k=0,\ldots,N$. That is, each subsequent image will have half the resolution along each axis. So I would like to better understand how this is modeled mathematically. My current understanding of the ideal downsampling of a *continuous* image $f$ is that one wants to compute the discrete image $\boldsymbol{g} \in \mathbb{R}^{2^{N-1}\times 2^{N-1}}$ such that:

$$g_{ij}=\int_{x_{2i}}^{x_{2(i+1)}}\int_{y_{2j}}^{y_{2(j+1)}}f(x,y)\,dy\,dx,$$

where pixel $(i,j)$ on the coarser level corresponds to some rectangle $[x_{2i},x_{2(i+1)}]\times[y_{2j},y_{2(j+1)}]$. The main trouble is that I am not given the continuous function, but instead some discrete data $\boldsymbol{h} \in \mathbb{R}^{2^N \times 2^N}$. To reconstruct a continuous function using a linear model I would have something of the form:

$$f(\boldsymbol{z}) = \sum_{i=1}^{2^N}\sum_{j=1}^{2^N}c_{ij}\phi_{ij}(\boldsymbol{z}),$$

where $c_{ij}$ are some coefficients, and $\phi_{ij}$ are some predetermined basis functions. A standard constraint used to derive $c_{ij}$ is the interpolation requirement: $h_{ij} = f(\boldsymbol{z}_{ij})$, where for example the samples are taken in the middle of each pixel: $\boldsymbol{z}_{ij} = \frac{1}{2}(x_i+x_{i+1}, y_j+y_{j+1})$. This is a linear system, and provided that the basis functions are linearly independent, then there is a unique set of coefficient $\boldsymbol{c} \in \mathbb{R}^{2^N\times 2^N}$ corresponding to $\boldsymbol{h}\in \mathbb{R}^{2^N\times 2^N}$.

Correct me if I am wrong, but I believe that if $\phi_{ij}$ are box functions, then computing the integral for $g$ is equivalent to using bilinear basis functions interpolation and then sampling at the midpoint. I believe a similar thing holds for higher degrees, where if $f$ is assumed to be formed by polynomials of degree $n$ then evaluating the integral would be equivalent to sampling a $n+1$ degree interpolated version of $\boldsymbol{h}$. The box filter version seems to be special in that it requires the basis functions to be Dirac deltas with a scaling factor of $\frac{1}{4}$ and $\boldsymbol{c} = \boldsymbol{h}$.

And this is the point where I am not certain about things anymore. I have seen the $sinc$ function described as an ideal interpolator in the context of the Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem, and I have also seen it discussed in the context of downsampling. How does such a $sinc$ downsampling relate to the above mathematical modelling of the problem? I am not quite sure how this downsampling is achieved in the first place or what it means when a discrete set of samples are considered. I understand that $\mathcal{F}[f * sinc] = \mathcal{F}[f] \cdot box$ can be used to cut off frequencies above the Nyquist frequency when $f$ is a continuous function. On the other hand I have seen people just put zeroes as DFT coefficients (notably this is the setting of a discrete signal). Is the idea that they consider $f$ a sum of Dirac deltas weighted by $h_{ij}$, and then consider the convolution with an appropriate $sinc$ to cut-off frequencies that are too high? This would essentially result in considering $sinc$ as basis functions. Where is the integration step that I have at the very beginning however? Am I misunderstanding how $sinc$ downsampling is supposed to work? Also there seem to be some concerns with ringing artifacts arising from the above? What is the mathematical reason for this?

Comment: Have you looked at https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/81529?

Answer (score 1):

An ideal sinc filtering operation will give you a maximally wide flat passband and no nonlinear artifacts when downsampling. This is covered by the sampling theoreme.

Unfortunately, an ideal sinc has infinite length, while your image have finite dimensions. Further, a (frequency domain) brickwall filter will have pre/post ringing around edges as negative terms are needed to be brickwall.

One solution is to use a sinc, but taper it to constrain its effective length. Lanczos is one popular class of windowed sinc functions used for image resampling.

Comment: My understanding is that the sampling theorem covers *continuous* functions, and infinitely many samples of those. Instead in the above we start with a discrete function $\boldsymbol{h}$. How does that fit into the $sinc$ downscaling? Should I mirror or toroidally extend the samples of $\boldsymbol{h}$ and assume that those were the product of sampling $f$? Thus the assumption being that: $f(z) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} h_k sinc\left(\frac{z-kT}{T}\right)$, where $h_k = f(kT)$? Where does the integration over each pixel come into play? I am looking for the mathematical model's motivation.