# Applying 2D Sinc Interpolation for Downsampling in the Fourier Domain (DFT / FFT)

Tags: matlab, dft, interpolation, frequency-domain, downsampling

Related to [The Proper Way to Do Sinc Downsampling (DFT Downsampling) for Uniformly Sampled Discrete Signals with Finite Number of Samples](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/72433/the-proper-way-to-do-sinc-downsampling-dft-downsampling-for-uniformly-sampled), how can one apply Sinc downsampling in the DFT / FFT domain for a 2D signal?

What are considerations when implementing it in MATLAB?

This the downsampling case of in [Applying 2D Sinc Interpolation for Upsampling in the Fourier Domain (DFT / FFT)](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/81493/applying-2d-sinc-interpolation-for-upsampling-in-the-fourier-domain-dft-fft) as requested in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in [Applying 2D Sinc Interpolation for Upsampling in the Fourier Domain (DFT / FFT)](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/81493/applying-2d-sinc-interpolation-for-upsampling-in-the-fourier-domain-dft-fft), when dealing with the Since Interpolation / DFT Interpolation in $ n > 1 $ dimensions one could use the separability property of the DFT.

Hence one could use the code from The [Proper Way to Do Sinc Downsampling (DFT Downsampling) for Uniformly Sampled Discrete Signals with Finite Number of Samples](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/72433/the-proper-way-to-do-sinc-downsampling-dft-downsampling-for-uniformly-sampled) as done in the upsampling case with the only difference being asking the output size to be smaller.

I updated the code in [Applying 2D Sinc Interpolation for Upsampling in the Fourier Domain (DFT / FFT)](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/81493/applying-2d-sinc-interpolation-for-upsampling-in-the-fourier-domain-dft-fft) to support this.
It even supports the case we upsample in one dimension while downasampling in the other.

Comment: I saw you changed the function name.